# Physical Mailing Address is in my email code, but I still get the "missing Physical Mailing Address" error on validation

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dynamic

I have an email developed using Dynamic Content (and note, that this issue seems to be prevalent when I'm using Dynamic Content for some reason), and as you can see, I have the business address information in my code (within the Dynamic Content section). The default dynamic content also has these address personalization strings:

[image]

However I still get the validation error that I'm missing the Business Address.

[image]

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?  Or is this a known issue with Dynamic Content?  Do I need to put the Business Address information outside of Dynamic Content?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the %%Member_Country%%, try adding this into your email code.
Hopefully that resolve the issue.

You can refer the article : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000336860&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1